# In boost, how to pass boost iterator to a function somehow casted as std::string

Tags: c++, boost, stdstring, boost-iterators

See specific question as a comment at the end of the following code.

```
std::string s("my sample string \"with quotes\"");

boost::escaped_list_separator<char> 
els(""," ","\"\'");

boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char> >::iterator 
itr;

boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char> > 
tok(s, els);

itr=tok.begin();
if (itr!=tok.end()) 
    fn_that_receives_pointer_to_std_string(itr); // <---- IS IT POSSIBLE TO SEND POINTER AND NOT HAVE TO CREATE A NEW STRING ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char> >::iterator` is not a pointer to `std::string`, but you can turn it into `std::string const *` with

```
&(*itr)
```

If a `const` pointer is not what you must pass, you may be able to do

```
std::string s(*itr);
```

and pass `&s`, depending on the ownership semantics of `fn_that_receives_pointer_to_std_string`. [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tokenizer/tokenizer.htm) does no distinguish between `iterator` and `const_iterator`, so the result of `operator*` is always `const`.

Answer (score 1):

`*itr` will actually return a `basic_string` instead of a `string`, so you need to convert one to another:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

void fn_that_receives_pointer_to_std_string(string* str)
{
    cout << "str: " << *str << endl;
}

int main()
{
   string s = "Field 1,\"putting quotes around fields, allows commas\",Field 3";
   tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> > tok(s);
   for(tokenizer<escaped_list_separator<char> >::iterator beg=tok.begin(); beg!=tok.end();++beg)
   {   
       string tmp(*beg);
       fn_that_receives_pointer_to_std_string(&tmp);
   }   
}
```

I don't like the idea to passing the memory address of a `string` to another function. Consider passing it by copy or by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's impossible.

It's exactly the reason why the rule ["take string parameters as `std::string`"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640669/how-string-accepting-interface-should-look-like) is wrong. `boost::iterator_range<const char*>` can be better when a template is inappropriate (separate compilation for example).