# File stream constructor

Tags: c++

File stream class cannot accept `string` as argument of its construtor, only C-string.

```
char fname[] = "file";
string fname_string ("file");
ifstream ifs (fname); //OK
ifstream ifs (fname_string); //Error
```

Why is it so? Is there any sense in that?

Answer (score 2):

Because in C++03, `std:istream` doesn't have a constructor which takes `std::string` as argument. However, [in C++11, it has!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream)

So as long as you use C++03, you've to do this:

```
std::ifstream ifs (fname_string.c_str()); //Ok in C++03 and C++11 both!
```

Only in C++11, you can do this:

```
std::ifstream ifs (fname_string); //Ok in C++11 only
```

Comment: Of course, I know that. But why? Why the authors of the C++ Stream Library did not created constructor with string as argument?

Comment: Yes, it must be the only reason )))

Comment: @mikithskegg: You can see this topic created by me : [Design of std::ifstream class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640281/design-of-stdifstream-class)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass a object of `std::string` you should use the `.c_str()` member function. This will convert it to an old style string.

The ifstream constructor only takes the old style strings. I'm guessing that ifstream probably doesn't allow implicit conversions because it could make a bunch of annoying hassles occur when objects that really don't represent filename strings get converted implicitly.

Comment: No, it's not about safety. The stream classes were just designed before there *was* a `std::string`.