# Why does std::ifstream constructor not take a std::string?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, std, ifstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Design of std::ifstream class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640281/design-of-stdifstream-class)
>   [Why does (i|o)fstream take a const char* parameter for a file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972151/why-does-iofstream-take-a-const-char-parameter-for-a-file-name)

Looking at std::ifstream's constructors, I find two:

```
ifstream ( );
explicit ifstream ( const char * filename, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in );
```

Why does the second one take a `const char *` and not a `const std::string &`?

Is this some kind of avoidance of circularity or forward reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a simple omission. Nobody thought about it in time. This has been corrected in C++11, where `std::string` is also accepted. From 27.9.1.7/3:

> `explicit basic_ifstream(const string& s, ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in);`
>
> *Effects:* the same as `basic_ifstream(s.c_str(), mode)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is out of date. Upgrade it and you should find a `std::string` constructor.